# WITHOUT using parseInt or toString, write a function that will take a binary string and convert it to a number

Tags: string, binary, parseint

Binary describes a number expressed in only 1s and 0s. Learning binary simply means learning a new way that count and calculate numbers. You really don't need to know binary for most cases while coding; however, some coding challenges that you could get in an interview will require you to manipulate binary numbers. Treat this as an opportunity to learn a neat new skill and begin your job search preparation.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct platform to post this.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply to take a string representing the bits of an unsigned value, it can be done with the following pseudo-code:

```
accumulator = 0
for each character in string:
    multiply accumulator by two
    if character is '1':
        add one to accumulator
```

For example, the string `1101` would be processed as follows:

```
character  accumulator
---------  -----------
                     0
        1            1 (0 * 2 + 1)
        1            3 (1 * 2 + 1)
        0            6 (3 * 2 + 0)
        1           13 (6 * 2 + 1)
```

That should be relatively easy to translate into pretty much *any* concrete procedural language.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, the code to convert the binary string to an integer would be:-

```
int strToInt(String str) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == '1')
             sum+=Math.pow(2, str.length() - 1 - i);
    }
return sum;
}
```

We know that the binary string is converted to as follows:-

int('10110') = 1 * 2<sup>4</sup> + 0 * 2<sup>3</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>2</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>1</sup> + 0 * 2<sup>0</sup>

which to think about is effectively multiplying 2<sup>length - 1 - index</sup> with the corresponding bit.

The code will run as follows:-

```
index                                       0      1     2     3     4
length-1-index                              4      3     2     1     0
2^(length-1-index)                          2^4    2^3   2^2   2^1   2^0
Corresponding Bits of bitstring             1      0     1     1     0

Multiplication of the above two columns     16      0     4    2     0
```

Summing the last row we get 22, which is the corresponding integer.